# Error when trying to get images from DocumentDirectory path

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimage, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to store an array of images in **DocumentDirectory** path 
This is my code to store the images

```
 let img = photo //Change to be from UIPicker
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img!)!
    do {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        try data.writeToFile("\(documentsPath)(myImage)", options: [])

    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
```

And this is how I get the images

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let readData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: "\(documentsPath)(myImage)", options: [])
        let retreivedImage = UIImage(data: readData)
        image = retreivedImage
        photos.append(image!)

    }

    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
```

My problem is when I save the first image I can load it but when I add more then 1 image and save it I can't reload it

Comment: what do you mean  "more then 1 image and save it I can't reload it"?

Comment: how are you doing multiple?

Comment: I mean i use a tableview its showing an array of images when i pick first image and close the app and open it again the image will show up but when i add another image to the array and close the app and open it again no image show up

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. This code was working for me.

You can Download and save image to Document directory like below using swift3.0

```
/// Get Document directory path
```

var directoryPath: String {

```
    let baseUrl = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)

    print("Base Url: \(baseUrl.first!)")

    return baseUrl.first!
}
```

/// add a image to Document directory

func addImage(_ image: UIImage, name: String) -> Bool {

```
    var path = directoryPath

    path.append("/\(name)")

    return FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: path, contents: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0), attributes: nil)
}

/// fetch a image from document directory
```

func fetchImage(name: String) -> UIImage? {

```
    var imagePath = directoryPath

    imagePath.append("/\(name)")

    if  FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagePath) {

        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)!

    } else {

        return nil

    }
}
```